# Using JFactory::getDocument in Joomla 3.0 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have some code that i can insert into my Joomla 3.0 page that will call the java correctly. I am trying to switch to use the JFactory::getDocument for my java functions since it is native to Joomla.

Here is the working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery demo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
   <script src="media/jui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a").click(function(event){
         alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
         event.preventDefault();
       });
     });
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

here is what i have tried that is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery demo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
   JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('
(function($) {
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a").click(function(event){
         alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
         event.preventDefault();
       });
     });
 }) (jQuery);
');?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Any assistance with this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
<?php
   $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $js = '
       (function($) {
           $(document).ready(function(){
              $("a").click(function(event){
                 alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
                 event.preventDefault();
              });
           });
        })(jQuery);';
   $document->addScriptDeclaration($js);
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help that yeilds a blank page for the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Normally This will work

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();

$document->addScriptDeclaration('(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(event){
     alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
     event.preventDefault();
   });
 });
 }) (jQuery);
');
```

This will not work then try to use the JS code to an external Js file and then include using with following code.

```
$document->addScript("your script page full path");
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: So i put this `code`<script src="media/jui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a").click(function(event){
         alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
         event.preventDefault();
       });
     });
   </script>`/code`

Comment: in a js file and used the call on the page for add script and it does not seem to be pulling the file even if i put the complete path from my E:\... drive to the script

Comment: It will works.. Provide correct path $document->addScript("http://yourdomain.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js"); .You did any edit on joomla core files ? like factory or library files ?

Comment: you show that path as the path to the jquery file. should it not be set to the script that i wrote the `code`<script>..</script>`/code` in and no i have not edited any of the joomla core files

Comment: yes you can add your script in separate js and try that.instead of jquery addScript I just show the usage

Comment: yes that did not work for this either. It seems that the JFactory and document call are not working properly